# Facebook login integration get mobile no from FB?

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook login for users those who registered with email id in facebook.so when the user login I'm using his email id to check the user is already registered with my app.and nothing problem with that.

Now imagine when a user trying to login with my app who registered with mobile number in facebook.

> How can I get his username ie, mobile number instead of email id if the user registered with mobile number and how can i detect it the registration done with either mobile number or email id  ?

Recently I came to know facebook restricted to provide even whole friends of a user so I'm very afraid about fetching the username ie, mobile number  of a user and i have surfed a while but unable to find the related documents too.

Plz help me out friends.

Comment: use facebook_id as primary key i.e you can get it in such a way

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email");
                    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
                    graphRequest.executeAsync();

Comment: U mean i should use `user_id` from fb to handle user login instead of using email_id or phone number to identify ?

Comment: I think you can use the user_id@facebook.com as the email for the mobile  no. user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone number of a Facebook user is *not* available via API.

Comment: Actually if a user registering with phone number in fb that is his username right.so u mean that username ie, phone number itself they won't return via API ? I din't mean phone number from user personal details.

Comment: If that is the case how i can manage in server the login with fb to handle the case users registered with either email or phone number ? please tell me.

Comment: No, that is not necessarily their user name. And the `username` field has been removed with API v2.0. // You should identify users by their FB user id. And if your app _needs_ an email address or a phone number, then you will have to ask users to provide that in a separate step, if you can’t get an email from Facebook. (Any validation of either email or phone number you’d have to perform yourself in that case.)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments.